# Why overflows are omitted in the non-restoring hardware binary division algorithm?

Tags: hardware, algorithm, arithmetic-division

I'm reading a book about a non-restoring binary division algorithm, for example `52_octal` divided by `41_octal`:

```
Round | Action            | Divisor | Remainder(6 bits) appended Quotient(6 bits)  
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
0     | Init Value        | 100 001 | 000 000 101 010
      | R>0, RQ << 0, Sub | 100 001 | 000 001 010 100
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
1     | R=R-D             | 100 001 | 100 000 010 100
      | R<0, RQ << 0, Add | 100 001 | 000 000 101 000 <--- Now the remainder bits overflow!
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
2     | R=R+D             | 100 001 | 100 001 101 000
      | R<0, RQ << 0, Add | 100 001 | 000 011 010 000 <--- Overflow again.
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
3     | R=R+D             | 100 001 | 100 100 010 000
      | R<0, RQ << 0, Add | 100 001 | 001 000 100 000 <--- Overflow again.
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
4     | R=R+D             | 100 001 | 101 001 100 000
      | R<0, RQ << 0, Add | 100 001 | 010 011 000 000 <--- Overflow again.
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
5     | R=R+D             | 100 001 | 110 100 000 000
      | R<0, RQ << 0, Add | 100 001 | 101 000 000 000 <--- Overflow again.
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
6     | R=R+D             | 100 001 | 001 001 000 000
      | R>0, RQ << 1, Sub | 100 001 | 010 010 000 001
------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------
      | Shift R-part right 1 bit    | 001 001 000 001
                                    | R=11_oct | Q=1_oct
End
```

Why won't this cause an error? I follow this algorithm and it gives right answer...

Comment: This algorithm at first glance looks quite similar to the ones I've coded on processors without division, before. (I've written floating point libraries for commercial compilers and routinely use loop-unrolled, non-restoring division -- my numerical routines are always at the top of competitive performance magazine comparison articles, as a result of care -- especially with division.) Doesn't your book carefully explain to you why it works?

Comment: @jonk: It's a book for preparing a test so it doesn't provide a proof (but "why it work" did take me several hours trying). But it does provide a "step by step how it is executed", which is (all the) information I can provide. I searched the Wiki but it explains the software version. And I'm very happy that I'm talking to an expert:)

Comment: Hopefully, the following will help you a little.

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

Since you indicate that you aren't familiar with non-restoring division, then consider the following discussion about multiplication to set a mental context for what follows:

- With computer multiplication, the *multiplicand* and the *multiplier* are usually imagined to be of equal width (same number of bits), though they do not necessarily need to be the same. The width of the resulting product value must be the sum of the width of multiplicand and the multiplier. This guarantees that you cannot overflow the output result.
- You may consider the idea, also, of now adding a small remainder *offset* (which may be zero and therefore not require any effort) to this product to complete the final result.
- This is called a multiply-accumulate operation (or MAC, for short.)
- If the *multiplicand* has \$N\$ bits and the *multiplier* as \$M\$ bits, and the *addend* requires no more than the larger of either \$N\$ or \$M\$ bits, then the MAC operation result will fit within \$N+M\$ bits. (An *addend* that meets this size restriction will not overflow the product result.)

(In the above MAC operation, the multiplication product becomes the *augend* for the following addition, with the small *offset* being the *addend*.)

Now, to compose a division operation that may reverse the above MAC operation, you start with a dividend that is \$N+M\$ bits wide. (Since this is the width of the above MAC result.) You also then consider a divisor that is \$M\$ (or \$N\$) bits wide to parallel the concept of the earlier *multiplier* (or *multiplicand*.) The quotient is then \$N\$ (or \$M\$) bits in width to parallel the concept of the earlier *multiplicand* (or *multiplier*.) The remainder will, of course, be \$M\$ (or \$N\$) bits wide.

I think you should be able to see why the above paragraph is a correct reversal of the MAC operation. If you set things up where the *dividend* is the original MAC result and the *divisor* is taken as the original *multiplier*, then the *quotient* recovers the *multiplicand* and the *remainder* recovers the *addend*.

---

### Same Word Size (When N = M)

Suppose now that you are working with the fixed word size of some ALU, so that both the *multiplicand* and the *multiplier* are each \$N\$ bits wide, the *addend* is also \$N\$ bits wide, and the result of the MAC operation is then \$2\cdot N\$ bits wide.

To perform a division that reverses the above MAC operation, the *dividend* is then \$2\cdot N\$ bits wide, the *divisor* is \$N\$ bits wide, and the resulting *quotient* and *remainder* are each \$N\$ bits wide.

By now, you should realize that you must start out with a *dividend* that is twice the word width. And to avoid overflowing the *quotient*, you must be sure that the upper word of the *dividend* is smaller than the *divisor*. (If it isn't smaller, then the resulting *quotient* will be too large to fit.)

---

### Symmetry of Your Example

In your case, let's start out by looking at the original MAC operation required to get your starting values:

$$1_8 \times 41_8 + 11_8= 0052_8$$

Here, the *multiplicand* is \$1_8\$, the *multiplier* is \$41_8\$ and the *addend* is \$11_8\$. The resulting *product* is \$0052_8\$.

To reverse this operation, you set the double-wide *dividend* to \$0052_8\$ and the single-wide *divisor* to \$41_8\$. (As the operation proceeds, the resulting *quotient* and *remainder* will appear as the upper and lower portions of the prior double-wide *dividend* register.) Since your starting *dividend* fits within one word (6 bits here), the upper portion is simply zero (of course.)

So the reversing operation looks like this:

$$\frac{0052_8}{41_8}= 1_8\quad R\quad 11_8$$

All the pieces are still there; just in a different format now. I think you should be able to see the symmetry.

---

### Overview, Revisited

Here are a couple of initial tests you'd need to make:

1. If *divisor* is zero, terminate with "divide by 0" error.
2. If upper half of *dividend* is larger than *divisor*, terminate with "quotient overflow" error.

The above test-pair are required to avoid garbage and are performed prior to following the general algorithm.

The basic idea is that you start out generating the higher-order bits of the result, first, eventually generating the lowest-order bit at the very end of the process. So the subtraction (or addition) you perform starts with the high word of the double-word *dividend* pair. That's why the subtraction (or addition) you see takes place on what will eventually become the *remainder* and not on what will eventually become the *quotient*. After shifting (or rotating) through \$N\$ bits, the original *dividend* will be split up so that the *remainder* will be in the upper word and the *quotient* will be in the lower word. (The *quotient* is being manufactured one bit at a time in the lower word.)

---

### Non-Restoring Division; Hardware and Software Examples

The mathematical thoughts behind non-restoring division are pretty easy. Assume \$D\$ is your divisor and \$T_0\$ is your starting double-word *dividend*. Attempt a trial subtraction for \$i=1\$, where \$T_{i}=2\cdot T_{i-1} - D\$ (shifting \$T_{i-1}\$ left one bit before subtracting.) If this succeeds, continue on to compute \$T_{i+1}=2\cdot T_{i} - D\$, in similar fashion. But if it fails, then you need to fix things up by adding back \$D\$ before performing another shift. So in this case you want to compute \$T_{i+1}=2\cdot \left(T_{i} + D\right)-D=2\cdot T_{i} + D\$. That's the essence of the *non-restoring* idea.

Implementation, of course, is a little more complicated and will depend on whether or not this is being done in hardware or in software. Here's a sample diagram of how it might be implemented in hardware (this is EESE, after all):

[image]

(In the above diagram, \$Q\$ starts out as "0", of course.)

A software implementation can take a variety of forms (since it depends intimately upon the language and operators available to the programmer.) But here is one possible example that is semi-close to what you wrote:

[image]

First off, the above diagram illustrates what is called a *co-routine* by programmers. There are two distinct looping activities, one shown left and one shown right, which occasionally transition between each other. You can see that the exiting case for the right side is a little bit different than the exiting case on the left. This is to perform a final adjustment on the remainder, depending on which loop was active at the time.

When I write *rotate dividend* I mean both machine words; both *remainder* and *quotient*, which make up the entire *dividend* to start. But note that the subtraction or addition takes place only with one word; the *remainder*.

The ***LSB*** refers to the least significant bit of the entire *dividend*, which is the same thing as the ***LSB*** of the *quotient*. (It's up to you how you want to imagine. It's the same, either way.)

The ***CARRY***, as shown, means the carry bit that results from either the subtraction or the addition. For the subtraction case, I mean the usual ALU meaning where a subtraction is actually performed by first inverting all the bits of the *subtrahend* and then adding that, plus 1, to the *minuend*. (In subtraction, having the carry equal to 1 means that there was no borrow.)

Finally, if you are bothered by the details of the above implementation examples -- notably, that \$D\$ (the *divisor*) is subtracted from what seems to be the high-order word of the double-word *dividend* (the word that will eventually become your *remainder*) -- then just remember what I said, earlier: the method starts "...out generating the higher-order bits of the result, first..." If you think closely about this detail, I think it will make a lot more sense.

---

### Note

Looking at your example, I see that in step 6 you appear to *magically* insert a "1" bit over on the very right-most side of your final value. This is correct. But you didn't explain how it arrived there in your terse description. The above examples I've provided above discuss the details about how and why that bit arrives.